# How do i get a minimized window handle?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MinimizeCapture
{

    class WatchForWindow
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
        private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

        private static ManagementEventWatcher watcher = null;

        public static void StartWatching()
        {
            WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 2 Where TargetInstance Isa 'Win32_Process'");
            watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
            watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
            watcher.Start();
        }

        public static void StopWatching()
        {
            if (watcher != null)
            {
                watcher.Stop();
            }
        }

        private static void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            ManagementBaseObject obj = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
            string t = obj["Name"].ToString();
            GetHWND(t);
        }

        private static void GetHWND(string wName)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(wName, "Untitled - Notepad");

        }
    }
}
```

For example i opened a new chrome windows not tab but window.
And then i used a breakpoint on: `string t = obj["Name"].ToString();` and i see that `t` contain chrome.exe
But then in the end i see `hWnd` is 0. And i want to get minimized window/s handle(hWnd) not window that is in the front but windows that are in the back(minimized).

EDIT:

0xA3 maybe there is other way to detect each chrome opened window not by handle and take a screenshot of this window while it's minimized ? I can get current windows opened screenshots minimized even if chrome have 2 windows opened. The problem is not i want to detect automatic the windows and get it's screenshots when it's minimized . Chrome any other process/application i run that is minimized.

This is class i use today now to get windows that are minimized snapshot . [WindowSnap.cs](http://pastebin.com/w135fV38) the class name is WindowSnap.cs and this is the second class WindowSnapCollection.cs: [WindowSnapCollection.cs](http://pastebin.com/52ZqtVwR) and this is how i use the first class to add the windows to a listBox in form1 then when i move between the items in the listBox i see each window taken snapshot in a pictureBox:

```
this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
```

This is the GetallWindows method from WindowSnap.cs class:

```
public static WindowSnapCollection GetAllWindows(bool minimized, bool specialCapturring)
        {
            windowSnaps = new WindowSnapCollection();
            countMinimizedWindows = minimized;//set minimized flag capture
            useSpecialCapturing = specialCapturring;//set specialcapturing flag
            EnumWindowsCallbackHandler callback = new EnumWindowsCallbackHandler(EnumWindowsCallback);
            EnumWindows(callback, IntPtr.Zero);
            return new WindowSnapCollection(windowSnaps.ToArray(), true);
        }
```

Comment: Do you vary the `lpWindowName`, or are you searching for a window in the class `chrome.exe` with the name "Untitled - Notepad", as that seems unlikely to work?  And is `chrome.exe` the right class name for a Chrome window?  I don't have Chrome installed at the moment, but I'd double check that with Spy++ or something similar.

Comment: Two things: 1. Chrome is special. Only the parent process has a main window handle. 2. You pass the process name as the first parameter into the FindWindow function. This parameter should be the window class name (_Chrome_WidgetWin_1_ for Chrome).

Comment: Updated my question with how i get the windows snapshots today . And now i want to make that if i open a new windows it will detect it automatic and use the WindowSnap.cs class to get it's snapshot and add it to the listbox in form1.